# Текстуры и картинки в HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, графика, html5-canvas

Я пишу браузерную игру, где для отрисовки игроков (танчиков) использую графические примитивын: полигоны, круги, и.т.п. Я хочу делать танки не монотонно-зелёными или серыми, а также добавить камуфляж. Вопрос: Как наложить/нарисовать текстуру на круге, полигоне ? Дополнительный вопрос, который закроет предыдущий: Можно ли отрисовывать в канвасе